# make object map in data-table in Vuetify

Tags: vuetify.js, v-data-table

I can't put a map object in a datatable in vuetify.

It returns this error "Invalid prop : type check failed for prop "items". Expected Array, got Map"

Do you know how to do it?

Here is a capture of my code.

my data type is a map in vue.js : `dataset: new Map(),`

in this map, I put as key an id and as values a dictionary containing values and keys as below :

Page : [page display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaIfW.png)

Code : [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuZvd.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide code instead of screenshot ? Also, can you add the dataset definition ?

Comment: Can you add the definition of `dataset` ?

Comment: Dataset is a map object in JS

Answer (score 1):

In order to work with `Map` using vue.js you need to make the `dessets` Map reactive.

To do this, a simple way would be to re-create the `Map` object for each object of your loop

```js
this.desserts = new Map(this.desserts.set("foo", {score:1}));
```

Then, you can convert the map using a `computed` property like this for example :

```js
Array.from(this.desserts).map(([key,value]) => ({name:key, ...value}))
```

Note that here i added the key as a `name` property to show it in the table

## Example

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  computed: {
    items() {
      return Array.from(this.desserts).map(([key, value]) => ({
        name: key,
        ...value
      }))
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      headers: [{
          text: 'Name',
          value: 'name'
        },
        {
          text: 'Title',
          value: 'title'
        },
        {
          text: 'Body',
          value: 'body'
        },
      ],
      desserts: new Map()
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      for (let i=0; i < res.length; i++){
        const post = res[i]
        this.desserts = new Map(this.desserts.set(post.id, {
          title: post.title,
          body: post.body,
        }))
      }
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.3.4/dist/vuetify.min.css'>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.3.4/dist/vuetify.min.js'></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-data-table :items="items" :headers="headers">

  </v-data-table>
</div>
```

Comment: even with "values()" or "keys()" it gives me the same error

Comment: Edit my answer check the snippet now

Comment: yes there are no more errors

Comment: No, because I can't read the keys and values

Comment: I edit my answer to use `Map`. This might be it now

Comment: the problem is that I am in a for loop so I have to add several elements in my map.
How can I do that ?
Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: As I did in the post, you can do `this.desserts = new Map(this.desserts.set("foo", {score:1}));` instead of just `this.desserts.set("foo", {score:1});`

Comment: by doing this it only shows me the last line : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1aWw.png

Comment: Hav you done `this.datasets = new Map(this.datasets.set(id, ....) ` ?

Comment: yes, that's what I did

Comment: Check now. I've edited using a fetch and a for loop almost as you did.

Comment: in fact, even with your code, it only shows me the last element of the map.
I modify my images in my first answer.
see 'Page' and 'Code' please in my first answer.

Comment: Can you provide a codepen or codesanbox ? Hard to help without all the code here i guess

Comment: I found my mistake, my key was identical so he will replace her.
@RenaudC5 thank you for your help

Comment: Nice ! Do not hesitate to up my answer or accept it if you fells it answers the question ;)

Comment: Converting map into array fixed my issue